# For WordPress element editor frontend.min.js And jquery.min.js conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
For WordPress element editor frontend.min.js And jquery.min.js conflict.

Error message:
 Uncaught TypeError: e.elementorWaypoint is not a function
   at Frontend.waypoint (frontend.min.js:2)
    at Counter.onInit (frontend.min.js:2)
    at Counter.Module.trigger (frontend-modules.min.js:2)
    at Counter.e.each.r.<computed> [as trigger] (frontend-modules.min.js:2)
    at init (frontend-modules.min.js:2)
    at Counter.Module (frontend-modules.min.js:2)
    at Counter.child [as constructor] (frontend-modules.min.js:2)
    at new child (frontend-modules.min.js:2)
    at Counter._createSuperInternal (frontend.min.js:2)
    at new Counter (frontend.min.js:2)
```

Introduce and introduce local via Google CDN jQuery.js It's not all right.It also tried to replace $JQ with JQ, which did not help.I need help and time is running out.

[error message images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed7L2.png)

Comment: Try saying that another way.

Comment: WordPress elementor's frontend.min.js And jquery.min.js There is a conflict

Comment: delete jquery.min.js After that, the website will not prompt the error message, but the JQ file I wrote did not jquery.min.js support.